# Existing library or method to calculate the first available slot to insert a range?

Tags: php

Honestly, I feel like this is from a CompSci test that I would have taken when in college, but I'm unclear of the best method to tackle this. That said, it seems to be a classic "scheduling" issue so I suspect there is a library or well-defined solution to it. Unfortunately, when I Google various terms on this problem, I get a lot of PHP cronjob schedulers due to the keywords.

Okay, so I am building a feature where I look at a calendar for a user and want to insert an event that has a duration X. The objective is to insert the event in the first available spot.

Like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdDa6.png)

Note, the data is actually originally in a series of models where the class has this defined:

- event.StartDateTime
- event.EndDateTime

I converted that to a matrix in the screenshot.

Is there a library or well defined algo to solve this? Right now, I'll be doing this using a very simple brute force loop of just testing every possible time to see if the "start" and "end" are unused. I know that everything from event scheduling to CPU scheduling will solve this issue, so would love to know of existing libraries etc that do this but won't require that I read through asm for a CPU scheduler. :)

Language is PHP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
you should not to ask for specific library :) Try to solve it by self, or ask for best sollution, but not for specific library

Answer (score 0):

I took a moment to map this out and realized it's actually quite simple if you look at the problem correctly.

An easy solution is to map it out like this:

```
startTime ... endTime
```

Then, you can compute the gap of time between an endTime and the next startTime:

```
startTime ... endTime ... gap
```

Like this:

```
900 .. 1000 (gap between 1000->1100 = 60min)
1100 ... 1200 (gap between 1200-1400 = 120min) 
1400 .. 1415 ...
```

You have to add entries for the start and end of the work day for the schedule to review.

Now it's very simple! Just go down this list and find the first spot where:

```
gap >= timeRequested
```

Then you have your timeslot.